# GoInstant: Match a single array element with $goQuery?

Tags: goinstant, goangular

Is it possible yet to query a key with an array value by a single array element with GoInstant GoAngular?  For example, if querying a list of items with the following keys/properties, can I select only items that belong to a single user?

```
item: {
    name: 'Item name',
    description: 'A longer description of the item and its details',
    category: 'Business',
    user_ids: [1,3,7,15]  //This is an array of user id's because items
                          //have a many-to-many relationship with users
}
```

I tried this query but it does not return anything:

```
var queryResults = $goQuery('items', { user_ids: 1 }, { limit: 10 }).$sync();
```

I believe this is the proper syntax according to the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element), but I'm not sure if GoInstant has implemented this operator yet.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you expect, it's definitely a bug! Stay tuned, I'll update this  Answer once it's been fixed.